# Does a Contributor License Agreement prevent future employment with that company?

Tags: contributor-agreements

While job searching I thought it'd be nice to get a leg up on the hiring process for this particular company by contributing to the their open source projects.

Signing a CLA makes sense, however I just wanted to make sure this doesn't bar me from employment with them to some degree.

Comment: Why do you think it would?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course not. A CLA says (paraphrased) "code I write belongs to you". Employment contracts say (either explicitly or implicitly) "code I write belongs to you". No problem there.

(What might be a problem is having a CLA with Company A and then going to work for Company B in the same field. But there would be ways to sort it out).

Comment: Not to get too nitpicky, but a CLA says "you may use code I write"; *copyright assignment* says "code I write belongs to you".  As Fedora and other organisations have found out, failure to make the distinction can cost a project quite a lot of goodwill, so it seems best to me not to propagate the confusion.  That doesn't detract from your answer, though; +1 from me.